# Django save ManytoMany with Custom UserModel

Tags: django, many-to-many, modelform

i have 2 models, "Tienda" and my custom "MyUser"

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True,
    ...



tienda(models.Model)
...
user = ManytoManyfield(MyUser)
```

---

then, my form.py is

```
addtiendaform(ModelForm)
class Meta:
        model = tienda
        fields = ('field1','field2',etc)
        exclude = ('user',)
```

---

finally, my view is:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user

tiendaview(request)
        id = get_user()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tienda_form = addtiendaform(request.POST)
        if tienda_form.is_valid():
            p = tienda_form.save(commit=False)
            p.user = id
            p.save()
            tienda_form.save_m2m()
```

But result is error: tienda need a value before manytomany relation can be used.

there´s an error in my code? please, if i need modify something tell me

Comment: Please post your exact code.. and the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

`is_valid` is a method not a variable. try:

```
if tienda_form.is_valid():
```

Theres no telling if that was your actually error you are getting, but that is one error. (you will need to post your stack trace for me to figure out your actual error.)

Comment: sorry, is not the problem, i forget write the "()", my error is the sintax